# How to update the distribution to 20.04 without deleting the hard drive data

Tags: 18.04, updates, 20.04

I want to update my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, but I do not know how to do this without deleting my previous information.

Comment: Read the release notes of the release you want to move to, ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes   You'll find a "*Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or 19.10*" section on *release-upgrade*

Comment: FYI:  You can upgrade via re-install... however I learnt today some of the features of that are being removed (*due to users have issues with it and filing bug reports, it's easier to remove the functionality than correct it given 3rd party packages are the major cause*) so I won't provide my normal how-to do that; but you can re-install without format using *something else* which is faster & an option if you don't want to *release-upgrade* as covered in the release notes I provided earlier.